# Integrating the DJI SDK, out of date tutorial?

Tags: android, android-studio, dji-sdk

I'm wondering if anyone here has any experience with the DJI Mobile SDK for Android?

I'm building an app for the Osmo Mobile (2) but I'm unable to follow the tutorial from DJI, I'm guessing it's out of date:

https://dji-dev.gitbooks.io/mobile-sdk-tutorials/content/en/Android/ImportAndActivateSDKInAndroidStudio/ImportAndActivateSDKTutorial_en.html

I'm stuck at this part: "Downloading and Importing Module to the Project"

*"Unzip the Android SDK package, go to File -> New -> Import Module on the top bar of Android Studio. Then enter the "API Library" folder location of the downloaded Android SDK package in the Source directory field. A "dJISDKLib" name will show in the "Module name" field. Press Next and finish button to finish the settings."*

I downloaded the SDK from here: https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android

The issue is, there is no "API Libary" in the source directory, and not anywhere else in any sub directory.

I would be glad to hear if anyone managed to successfully integrate the SDK into their application I would be glad to hear so!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The dji-dev's Gitbook is now deprecated, please refer to the iOS & Android tutorials section in DJI Developer Website: https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/introduction/index.html.

Comment: I've succesfully followed this tutorial: developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/… I'm not quite sure if I can start using the SDK after following this tutorial, without further action from my part?

Answer (score 1):

Use this link for the latest instructions to get the DJI sample app up and running quickly: https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/quick-start/index.html#android-sample-app

The instruction set you are using for importing the DJI api are out of date by about 6 months. The current system is much easier and allows you to use the compile command to grab the DJI api.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I've succesfully followed this tutorial: https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-integrate.html        I'm not quite sure if I can start using the SDK after following this tutorial, without further action from my part?      PS: Trying to run the sample app resulted in a failed registration, multiple people seem to be experiencing this issue